# Getting Year from Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a timestamp in my database which I need to get the year from. The timestamp is saved as below

```
Timestamp {seconds: 1574096026, nanoseconds: 716000000}
```

How can I get the year from the above timestamp I tried `new Date(timestamp).getFullYear()` but it doesn't get me the year from the timestamp. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `new Date(timestamp.seconds + timestamp.nanoseconds/1E9).getFullyear()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear

Comment: @jaromandaX It gives the year as 1970

Comment: What do suppose to be year with this timestamp?

Comment: sorry, forgot to multiply the whole lot by 1000 :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because javascript "timestamp" is in milliseconds, you want `seconds * 1000 + nanoseconds / 1000000`

```js
let timestamp = {seconds: 1574096026, nanoseconds: 716000000}
let year = new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1e3 + timestamp.nanoseconds/1E6).getFullYear();
console.log(year);
```

Answer (score -1):

new Date(millisecond) receive millisecond as param, so you need to convert seconds and nanoseconds to millisecond first.

```js
const timestamp = {
  seconds: 1574096026, 
  nanoseconds: 716000000
}
const millisecond = `${timestamp.seconds}${timestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000}`;

const date = new Date(+millisecond);

console.log(date.getFullYear())
```

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score -1):

```js
var date = new Date(1574096026000+716000000/1000000);
console.log(date.getFullYear());
```